# How to customize dialog background?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want to implement a regular functional dialog, as well as text and a drawable on top of the gray overlay.

[image]

I did some research, but I was wondering if someone knows a better way of doing it. Here are a few thoughts:

1) The dirtiest way is to ditch the dialog and create a view with a fake dialog. That would be very easy, but is the least preferable because dialogs look different on different Android versions. Also it would be nice to reuse some of the Dialog stuff that has already been implemented.

2) A slightly better way would be to reuse the parts of Dialog xml file, but it's still "reinventing the wheel" a bit too much.

3) It would be great if I could just inflate a layout for the background and do dialog.setBackground but I couldn't find anything like that.

4) I tried inflating a layout and setting it using .setView() on the AlertDialog.Builder but it seems like it alters the dialog itself, not the background.

Comment: what specifically are you trying to create, you show a picture but im not sure what you want out of the picture

Comment: @tyczj I want the regular functionality of a dialog, as well as text and a drawable on top of the gray overlay. Is it possible to do that by altering the Dialog/AlertDialog or does it have to be the option 1)?